# Create a new Id column which start with 0000 and increments one by one in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new Id column to a data frame which should start from 0000 and increments

Expecting output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
df['id'] = pd.Series(np.arange(len(df))).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

**input**

```
Place   Number  Code
0   X   A   1
1   Y   B   2
2   X   C   3
3   Y   D   0
4   X   F   1
5   Y   G   2
6   X   H   5
7   Y   I   4
```

**output**

```
Place   Number  Code    id
0   X   A   1   0000
1   Y   B   2   0001
2   X   C   3   0002
3   Y   D   0   0003
4   X   F   1   0004
5   Y   G   2   0005
6   X   H   5   0006
7   Y   I   4   0007
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but for the last row Id was coming Nan, So modified as df['id'] = pd.Series(np.arange(len(df)+1)).astype(str).str.zfill(4) then its working fine